# Databinding - In XAML, how to databind to a property of the control created dynamically?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding

The control I created dynamically is a radiobutton, and I am trying to control the visibility of a hyperlinkbutton according to the IsChecked property of the radiobutton created in code-behind.

In my XAML file:

```
   <HyperlinkButton Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=tempRadio, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConvert}}"  Content="Insert Record" Click="addRecord" Background="Aqua" Foreground="White"></HyperlinkButton>
```

Apparently I don't think I should use ElementName in this case, since it is only for controls created in XAML.

In my C# file:

```
  public RadioButton tempRadio;

  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this:

first set the binding target on your hyperlink

hyperlinkButton.BindingTarget = tempRadio.IsChecked;

then set the binding:
hyperlinkButton.SetBinding(hyperlinkButton.BindingTarget, CreateValueBinding());

private Binding CreateValueBinding()
        {
            var valueBinding = new Binding();
            valueBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            valueBinding.NotifyOnValidationError = true;
            valueBinding.ValidatesOnExceptions = true;
            valueBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit;
            valueBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(this.DataMemberBinding.Path.Path);
            return valueBinding;
        }

Comment: But is there a way to do this from XAML to refer to the dynamically created radiobutton. Thanks

Comment: I don't think so, I think if you create something in code behind the rest must also be hooked up there.  If you need to have your Radio in XAML then maybe you would want to create it with Visibility.Collapsed. This is REALLY hard when there is no code to provide context.